# Remove the most current kernel

Tags: boot, kernel, virtualization

I noticed that the "similar questions" responses are several (if not a decade) old so wanted to just check is there is a more recent way of removing the most current kernel.

During the updates the other day, the kernel was updated to 5.19.0-42 but now the machine will not boot.  I did display the boot messages and it hangs at "systemd-user-sessions.service".  I am running version 22.04 as a VM under Virtualbox.

I have for now been pressing ESC and choosing the previous kernel (5.19.0-41) to boot the machine.

P.S.  I actually have three similar VMs (v22.04 VMs) and all are displaying the same problem.

Comment: Running away from the "current" kernel (and all subsequent kernel versions) is unwise, and should only be considered after an investigation into why the current kernel doesn't boot.

Comment: How does removing the current kernel (5.19.0-42) prevent subsequent updates?  If there is a way to make the previous kernel (5.19-0.41) the default for booting until the next kernel is released would be a solution.  Per above, the existing problem is with kernel 5.19.0-42 and the systemd-user-sessions.service module.